# Liquid width within fixed width parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a centered layout with 960px of width. Within the wrapper I want a Slideshow, that is 100% of width **(the browsers width)**.

How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="wrapper"> //960px
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="slider"> //100%
        Slider-content
    </div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.

How to make a DIV, that is within a fixed width DIV, to be the width of the browser.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper"> //960px
    <div class="slider"></div> //100% of browser width
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`div.slider` will already be `100%` width, since block-level elements like `div` already expand horizontally to fill all their parent's space unless otherwise specified. This is going to be true for `div.text` as well.

If you are asking how to create the 960px centered wrapper, the techniques are pretty standard. Either:

```
div#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto; /* horizontal margin set to "auto" pushes <div /> to center
    width: 960px;
}
```

or

```
div#wrapper
{
    left: 50%;             /* put left edge at 50% */
    margin-left: -480px;   /* move left edge back by 480px = half width.
                              this makes the center of #wrapper match center of page */
    position: absolute;    /* position: absolute makes the left: 50% line work */
    width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at ways of including the `slideshow` div outside of the `wrapper` div if the `wrapper` is to be 960px and the `slideshow` is 100% of browser width.

Typically, absolute positioning of the `slideshow` div inside the `wrapper` div won't affect the dimensions of its container (`wrapper`) div but you lose some control in centering the contained (`slideshow`) div.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing #wrapper to .wrapper so that you can reuse your wrapper class later down the page. Then, I recommend the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper"> //960px
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div><!-- end .wrapper -->

<div class="slider"> //100% of browser viewport
  Slider-content
</div><!-- end .slider -->

<div class="wrapper"> //960px
  <div class="text"></div>
</div><!-- end .wrapper -->
```